# Align navigation bar to center in css and add separator lines between buttons

Tags: html, css, text, navigation, alignment

I have this basic navigation bar, and I want to make the menu buttons centered, and also I want a separating line between them. Also I think my code may have some unnecessary parts.
Here is an image of what I am trying to create:

[image]

Here is my source code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>NOT!fy</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav" align="center">
<span>
<ul>
<li><img src="img/notify_icon.png" alt="notify_icon" width="30px" /></li>
<li><a href="href">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="href">FEATURE SET</a></li>
<li><a href="href">WHO ARE WE</a></li>
<li><a href="href">INDIEGOGO</a></li>
<li><a href="href">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS file:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#nav {
font-family: Century Gothic, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
color: #fff;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color: #353539;
height: 50px;
width: auto;
font-weight: bold;
border-width:0px;
opacity:0.95;
}
#nav ul {
padding: 7px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
} 
#nav ul li {
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
float: left;
margin: 0px;
padding-left:50px;
}
#nav ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #d2d2d2;
text-align: center;
display: block;
padding: 10px;
margin: 0px;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
color: #ffd200;
}

body
{
background-color:#c5c5c5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vcUQs/)

This should do what you like.

`margin:0 auto` centers elements on the page, so you simply had to set the li parent to an `auto` width with this css attatched.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great! Another problem is that when I resize the window, the content changes, some menu items get to a second line. How can I get the content to stay, whatever I do, and the user has to scroll if he wants to see all the content? I hope I was clear:)

Comment: And also when I change the nav img width from 30px to 50px, the whole thing gets messy. Like this: http://i.imgur.com/OVpLHiL.png
I did not change anything else! Now the icon is as it is supposed to be, but everything else is not! And the first separator line is somehow in its correct place too. I don't understand, and I am freaking out! Please help :))